# Can not run test on remote machine using Serenity

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

I want to run a simple test that remote on a local docker container:

```
$docker ps -a  
CONTAINER ID         IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES 
e559bc98ae9c        selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:latest   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   10 seconds ago      Up 6 seconds       0.0.0.0:4444->4444/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5900->5900/tcp   new_selenium
```

I can run it successfully with selenium config:

```
driverWeb = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(url), chromeBrowserCapabilities();
```

But when I try to let Serenity control the webdriver life cycle, have an error:

`` Dec 06, 2019 5:31:15 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()` [main] INFO net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - STEP ERROR: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver F[main] INFO net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - STEP ERROR: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (session not created: No matching capabilities found Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host: 'a77e0051b738', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_222' Driver info: driver.version: unknown remote stacktrace: #0 0x55d7b005a7e9 <unknown> ``

This is serenity.conf:

```
webdriver {   driver = chrome   
              timeouts {
                     implicitlywait = 7000
                     fluentwait = 10000
              } 
         } 
headless.mode = false

chrome.capabilities.acceptSslCerts = true 
chrome.capabilities.handlesAlerts = true

#
# Chrome options can be defined using the chrome.switches property
# 
chrome.switches="""--start-maximized;--test-type;--no-sandbox;--ignore-certificate-errors;
                       --disable-popup-blocking;--disable-default-apps;--disable-extensions-file-access-check;
                       --incognito;--homepage=about:blank;--disable-infobars;--disable-gpu"""

webdriver.chrome.driver = "drivers/chromedriver" 
webdriver.gecko.driver = "drivers/geckodriver"
```

I do not know why have this error and how to fix it.

Please help me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your node is running in docker then try to configure the drive as remote one.

Here is an example taken directly from serenity documentation (https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/serenity-grid.html#_configuring_your_serenity_tests)

```
webdriver {
  driver = remote
  remote {
      url="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
      driver=chrome
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to set capability for that. You can distinguish between local and remote before running the tests, as given below.

And run as;

> mvn clean install verify -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true

```
# Remote
webdriver {
  driver = remote
  remote {
      url="http://YOUR_IP:YOUR_PORT/wd/hub"
      driver=chrome
  }
}

#Local
#webdriver {
#  driver = chrome
#}

zalenium {
    screenResolution = "1280x720"
    idleTimeout = 150
}

headless.mode=false
serenity {
  tag.failures = "true"
  linked.tags = "issue"
  restart.browser.for.each = scenario
}

drivers {
  windows {
    webdriver.chrome.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/chromedriver.exe
  }
  mac {
    webdriver.chrome.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/mac/chromedriver
  }
  linux {
    webdriver.chrome.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/linux/chromedriver
  }
}
```

Comment: I try your config but still error. 
I ran maven command include remote url as Serenity document:
`mvn test -Dwebdriver.remote.url=http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub -Dwebdriver.remote.driver=chrome clean verify`

Comment: I updated the answer. This whole serenity.conf and mvn command should work for you too.

Comment: No, I tried it but have another error. This is screenshot: https://prnt.sc/qdh1xw